# Merge two animations in Android

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm trying to combine two animations programmatically. In that simplified example:

```
 Animation translate = new TranslateAnimation(0, -100, 0, 0);
     translate.setDuration(1000);
 Animation zoom = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1);
     zoom.setDuration(1000);
```

I want the view make both animations at the same time. How can I do it?

The background of that question is because I have a more complex animation in a xml file and I want to combine that animation with a translation without modifying the original xml.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Merge two Animation using 
[AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can go for AnimationSet and add both animations into that AnimationSet and start that AnimationSet